My disk is full and I don't know why
I have a proxmox VM with a Ubuntu server 22.04 instance running docker.
System information tells me this
Usage of /:                       99.9% of 136.94GB
And du confirms it for the /dev/sda2 partition where the filesystem is
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                       137G  137G     0 100% /

But I can't find what the problem is. Doesn't seem to be a file or directory as I've gone through the whole directory tree and nothing is occupying the space.
I've tried to solve it using lsof | grep deleted as it seems to be the most suggested solution in a lot of posts here. It shows this, but I'm kind of new to this so I don't know how to interpret it and I tried to stop the apache2 process but had no success with it. I also read it might be a docker process doing something in the background but I wouldn't know how to diagnose that.
apache2    1913                             root    9u      REG                0,1          0                 2050 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    1918                             root    9u      REG                0,1          0                    3 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    4206                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                    3 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    4207                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                    3 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    4208                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                    3 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    4209                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                    3 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    4210                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                    3 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    5084                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                 2050 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    5085                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                 2050 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    5086                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                 2050 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    5087                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                 2050 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    5088                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                 2050 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2    5699                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                 2050 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)
apache2   21820                         www-data    9u      REG                0,1          0                    3 /memfd:opcache_lock (deleted)```

I've also read it might be related to LVMs but I'm truly new to this so I know even less about that, so any help would be truly welcome.
Edited:
As requested in comments sudo du -s /* 2>/dev/null output. Not sure what to do next because the biggest directory seems to be /mnt where my nas is mounted
0   /bin
257244  /boot
4   /cdrom
0   /dev
5624    /etc
12656   /home
0   /lib
0   /lib32
0   /lib64
0   /libx32
16  /lost+found
319336  /media
359096424   /mnt
16  /opt
0   /proc
60  /root
2220    /run
0   /sbin
1278098 /snap
4   /srv
4004868 /swap.img
0   /sys
76  /tmp
3543984 /usr
9973352 /var

df -h output
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                           593M  2,2M  590M   1% /run
/dev/sda2                       137G  137G     0 100% /
tmpfs                           2,9G     0  2,9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
//192.168.1.101/nas/Biblioteca  9,0T  3,5T  5,6T  39% /mnt/homeostasis
tmpfs                           593M  4,0K  593M   1% /run/user/1000

du -sh output for all the directories in /
0   bin
252M    boot
4,0K    cdrom
0   dev
5,5M    etc
11M home
0   lib
0   lib32
0   lib64
0   libx32
16K lost+found
311M    media
240G    mnt
16K opt
du: cannot access 'proc/219581/task/219581/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/219581/task/219581/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/219581/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/219581/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   proc
60K root
2,2M    run
0   sbin
1,3G    snap
4,0K    srv
3,9G    swap.img
0   sys
84K tmp
9,3G    var


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

A magic command which would've brought you to the correct conclusion faster is
 sudo du -xhs /*

where -x or --one-file-system switch makes du to skip directories on different file systems.
You'll immediately see that /mnt still takes up a huge amount of space without having to unmount the NAS etc.

Summary of investigation in comments: The user had data stored at the mountpoint used by their NAS. Unmounting the NAS and deleting the hidden data recovered the storage.
Some explanation:

The wonderful flexibility of being able to mount file systems at any point in the file system comes at a small cost: You can end up hiding files - usually by mistake.

(quoted from https://www.jorgensen.org.uk/files-hidden-by-mount-points.html which see for more info)
If your device is not mounted at the mountpoint you think it is, and you, for example, run a backup to the desired mountpoint, your system will happily do it and put the data there on your partition.
Then, if you later mount the device at that mountpoint, when you operate on the mountpoint, you are operating on the data on the device! That data you wrote to your partition gets hidden, but as you saw, it still takes up space.
To recover the space, unmount the device - make sure you really did - and delete everything at the mountpoint.
I cannot say how it happened in your case specifically. It depends on how you mount the device. I mount my shares through fstab and I haven't had this problem. I have seen it with devices that you just plug in and let the system mount them.

Before deletion, check that the (backup) files do not really belong on the NAS.  Depends upon how long backups are/must be kept.

I used to have this problem all the time, an NFS share on my NAS mounted through fstab at startup sometimes would fail to mount, a backup job with the share as a destination would start and next time I'd login I'd be greeted with No space left on device; adding _netdev to my fstab mount helped.

In this case the culprit was /mnt, however this isn't always the case; many times the problem is nested deeper into the filesystem, and it's e.g. with an application logging excessively in /var/log/*, or with something that's generating a lot of small files / some huge files elsewhere in the filesystem.
An easier way to spot the path that's taking up a lot of space, rather than running du from / and repeating it each time you descend into a directory (or each time you move up one level because you've determined that the problem isn't with the directory you're currently in), is using ncdu:
sudo apt install ncdu

If your disk is really full, to the point that you're unable to install new software:
sudo apt clean; sudo apt install ncdu

will remove packages cached by apt, freeing up some space before attempting to install ncdu.
sudo ncdu -x /

Will sort directories under / by size, giving a strong visual cue about which are taking up the most space, and will allow you to quickly descend on them / move up one level by hitting → / ←.

For example, in this case, following the lead given by the number of # to the left of each directory and descending first into home and then into user, I would have quickly discovered that something in ~/Documenti is taking up a whopping 11 GiB:


I'm a big fan of ncdu.

@OrganicMarble Me too; I discovered it by accident and it completely replaced du for spring-cleaning since!

ncdu breaks for huge amount of files (I imagine it sorts in memory). Then the sudo du -xh / | sort -h works.

@rapto I've never had that, but it may very well be, which would be kind of a shame.
